# Flutter bluetooth: Unable to show the bluetooth scanned devices on the flutter listview

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies

I have been trying to integrate fluter_blue_plus plugin in my flutter app but while scanning for the available devices i am getting an empty list without any available devices to pair with.

Here i am attaching screenshots and logs for the same to got through. I am struck here can you help me out with this.

Controller class file:

```
`import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class BluetoothController extends GetxController {

  FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;

  Future scanDevices() async {
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5));

    print("_________________________________________________________");
    print(flutterBlue.scanResults);
    print("_________________________________________________________");

    flutterBlue.stopScan();
  }

  Stream<List<ScanResult>> get scanResults => flutterBlue.scanResults;

}`
```

Widget where i am calling the controller to scan and show the available devices in listview:

```
`Widget _buildPopupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('List of available devices'),
      content: GetBuilder<BluetoothController>(
          init: BluetoothController(),
          builder: (controller) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        controller.scanDevices();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
//gradient: LinearGradient(
//colors: [Colors.indigo, Colors.blueAccent]),
                          boxShadow: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                blurRadius: 1.0,
                                offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0))
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Scan Devices!!!",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/40,
                                letterSpacing: 1,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                      stream: controller.scanResults,
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                        if(snapshot.hasData)
                          {
                            return ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                  final data = snapshot.data![index];
                                  return Card(
                                    elevation: 2,
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(data.device.name,
                                        selectionColor: Colors.black,),
                                        subtitle: Text(data.device.id.id),
                                        trailing: Text(data.rssi.toString()),
                                      ),
                                  );
                                });
                          }
                        else
                        {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Text("No devices found!!!"),
                          );
                        }
                        }
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('Close'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }`
```

```
Log output when i call the function:

/ViewRootImpl@7b87c05[MainActivity](13581): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@7b87c05[MainActivity](13581): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (13581): _________________________________________________________
I/flutter (13581): Instance of '_BroadcastStream<List<ScanResult>>'
I/flutter (13581): _________________________________________________________
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(13581): could not find callback wrapper
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(13581): Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner(13581): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=11 mScannerId=0
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(13581): STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(13581): Stop Scan with callback
```

My Android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have tried giving all the permission to the application in the settings in my android phone which is running android version 13 and one ui version 5.1.

But still not show the scanned devices in the list view.

I have given all the location permission in my phone for the mobile app.

I am attaching the mobile phone UI screenshot of the empty list below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsOnn.jpg)

Comment: Do you have BLE devices near you that are actually advertising? What kind of devices are you expecting in your list? Did you scan for devices using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I have a Hm-10 BLE module with me, Yes i have scanned the devices using nrf connect and it is showing the device in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems like you never actually listen for the scan result. The [usage section](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) of flutter_blue_plus shows an example:

```
// Start scanning
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

// Listen to scan results
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // do something with scan results
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
});

// Stop scanning
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```

This might already solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried that solution still there is a emply output.

Comment: Do you get a log output which contains the found devices or does this also not work?

Answer (score 0):

For me commenting the "flutterBlue.stopScan();" solved the issue

Not sure how this worked, the same code where "flutterBlue.stopScan();" was not commented on other project, in that project everything was working perfect

This is an example where the "flutterBlue.stopScan();" was not commented and the scan worked
https://github.com/tusharhow/flutter-bluetooth-app

The code which worked for me ->

```
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class BluetoothController extends GetxController {
  FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;

  Future scanDevices() async {
    // Start scanning
    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5));

// Listen to scan results
    var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      print('scanResults: ${results}');
      // do something with scan results
      for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
      }
    });
    print('subscription: $subscription');
    // Stop scanning
    //flutterBlue.stopScan();
  }

  // scan result stream
  Stream<List<ScanResult>> get scanResults => flutterBlue.scanResults;

  // connect to device
  Future<void> connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    await device.connect();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, working on android 13. I couldn't get the list of available devices.

The solution was to add the **android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"** flag to **BLUETOH_SCAN** in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

Before:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

After (works like a charm):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

Application permissions request may look like (you need to add support for Android < API 31):

```
Future<bool> requestBluetoothAccess() async {
  Future<bool> permStatus;
  if (Platform.isAndroid && await getAndroidSdk() > 30) {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.bluetoothScan,
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.bluetoothScan] == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        statuses[Permission.bluetoothConnect] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```